# While installing http_parser.rb ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

This error occurs when I try to install `http_parser` using gem:

```
dongl_000@LENNY ~/ava-home (master)
$ gem install http_parser.rb -v '0.6.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing http_parser.rb:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160217-15056-1hoiyfc.rb extconf.rb

creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating ruby_http_parser-x64-mingw32.def
make: *** No rule to make target '/c/Ruby22-x64/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h', need
ed by 'ruby_http_parser.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/http_p
arser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0
/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
```

How can I resolve this issue?

---

##### Versions

```
ruby : 2.2.1
rubyGem : 2.4.5
```

Comment: Why the .rb in the end of the gem name? Have you tried just **$ gem install http_parser -v '0.6.0'**?

Comment: @Ed de Almeida i get this: 
`ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'http_parser' (= 0.6.0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: http-parser`

Comment: And tried this alternative?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida for some silly reason the gem is actually named `http_parser.rb` - https://rubygems.org/gems/http_parser.rb/versions/0.6.0

Comment: Well... If so, then it is easy to know what is happening. This kind of error you got happens when you don't have all requisites to build the native extensions to a gem. Just yesterday I got a similar error trying to install postgresql, because my Fedora 22 installation had not a package name postgresql-devel. After I install it everything worked fine. Unfortunately it seems you are building under Windows and I just can't help you efficiently with this SO.

Answer (score 7):

I was going through this very same issue.

Looked up the Git Repository for the Gem (HTTP_Parser) and found out the reason for my problem:

[HTTP_Parser currently doesn't not support a Path with spaces](https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb/issues/47)

So I renamed my path and solved it.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve attempt to add the devkit to Ruby like this:

1. Install Ruby+DevKit from RubyInstaller: [Ruby Window Installers
   Downloads](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)
2. Check the "ridk install" checkbox at the end of the installer.
3. When RIDK runs, pick option 3 to install both MSYS and MINGW dev tools (`make` is provided with the MINGW stuff).

Open a fresh console (to get fresh environment variables), and rerun your gem or bundle command...and hope for the best.