# Jekyll installation error without sudo command

Tags: ruby, centos, jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll onto a server. I have Ruby installed at 2.7.0, and have Bundler installed as well, I'm using RVM and all of this went well during installation, however I can't seem to install jekyll when I run `gem install jekyll` or `sudo gem install jekyll` on a Cent OS server, the error I get is attached as:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200811-15255-1rx4cpi.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ruby_http_parser.c
compiling ryah_http_parser.c
linking shared-object ruby_http_parser.so
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--compress-debug-sections=zlib'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ruby_http_parser.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
```

Not sure why it's failing?

Comment: Does the directory name contain spaces? https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb/issues/47. and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40379944/1979953

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi It doesn't no, the full log is listed above in my original post, no mention of `http_parser` as a folder, so I don't think so.

Comment: Can you grep your `env` and disk for `compress-debug-sections`? Something's add that to your linker flags, and your linker doesn't understand this flag.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- You compiled Ruby with one compiler and are compiling extensions with a different one.
- You updated your system and your system compiler was upgraded.
- Your system compiler is old.

Install a new Ruby installation, if you can install jekyll there reinstall your current installation.